# How to implement an Android messaging application using AWS services?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, chat, messaging

I would like to implement an android messaging application like WhatsApp using Amazon AWS services, but I don't know the right service to do this.
Thank you all.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a Native Android App that invokes AWS Services, look at using the **AWS SDK for Kotlin**. This SDK works nicely within an Android Studio Project. To learn how to get up and running, see this AWS tutorial that walks you through building an Android app that (for demonstration purposes), invokes Amazon DynamoDB and SNS.

[Creating your first Native Android application using the AWS SDK for Kotlin](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/kotlin/usecases/first_android_app)